# SSIS package with changes to Excel file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel

I have an SSIS package that loads up an Excel file on daily bases; from time to time the file changes. It can have additional columns in the Excel worksheets.

How can I know if the Excel file has changed?

Is there a way to add that column automatically?

Comment: Add the column automatically, no. You *can* write your SSIS package so it only pulls columns A-F and ignores any new columns but then you'd never know if someone added additional columns. Hmmm